# Removed disabled users from groups in Azure AD- CSV file

Tags: azure, powershell

I have list of disabled users who are members of groups, these users objectid are in CSV file.
How to remove these users from those groups.

In Azure users and groups are identified through objectid and this is confusing to use the PowerShell.

How to remove the users from groups using Azure PS?

Comment: you probably want to add some more details to your specific situation such as the layout for your csv file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below ***PowerShell scripts*** to ***remove*** user details in multiple groups.

```
$userObjectid = <YourObjectid>
# here you will get the all the groups of user and removed with respective object id
Get-AzADUser -ObjectID $userObectid | Get-AzureADUserMembership | %{Remove-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $_ObjectId} | ft
```

Comment: Get-AzADUser : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ObjectId' because it is an empty string.

Comment: You have ObjectID in your .csv file. please refer [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/9008ac9c-ec30-4328-b2f5-f11c5d19a598/remove-all-ad-group-memebership-from-users-is-quotdisabled-accountsquot-ou?forum=winserverpowershell)